# jQuery datatables displays date as [object Object]

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

My code below works fine as far as querying a php web service and displaying the results using jQuery datatable.

The issue is that date values are being returned as [object object].

Any ideas why I am getting these values and how to resolve them?

My code is below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Init DataTables */
$("#example").dataTable( {
    "sProcessing" : true,
"sDom":'T<"clear">',
"sJQueryUI": true,
"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
"sDom": 'T<"clear"><"fg-toolbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-tl ui-corner-tr ui-helper-clearfix"lfr>t<"fg-toolbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-bl ui-corner-br ui-helper-clearfix"ip>',
    "sAjaxSource" : "Requests.php",
    "sAjaxDataProp" : "",
    "sDestroy" : false,
    "sScrollY": "400px",
    "fnServerData" : function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
        request = $.ajax({
            "dataType" : "json",
            "type" : "GET",
            "url" : sSource,
            "data" : aoData,
            "success" : fnCallback
        });
    },
         "aoColumns" : [
{
                        "mDataProp": "RequestID", "sWidth": "50px", sSortable: true,
                        "bSearchable": false,
                        "bSortable": false,
                        "fnRender": function (oObj)
                        {
                            // oObj.aData[0] returns the RequestID
                            return "<a href='details.php?RequestID="
                                + oObj.aData["RequestID"] + "'> " + oObj.aData["RequestID"] + " </a>";
                        }
                       },
          { mDataProp: "RequestDate",  "sWidth": "100px", sSortable: true },
          { mDataProp: "RequestorFullName",  "sWidth": "150px", sSortable: true },
          { mDataProp: "PrimarySiteContactDisplay",  "sWidth": "250px", sSortable: true },
          { mDataProp: "RequestLocation",  "sWidth": "150px", sSortable: true },
          { mDataProp: "RequestDescription",  "sWidth": "200px", sSortable: true },
          { mDataProp: "RequestStatus",  "sWidth": "100px", sSortable: true },

        ],
      })
$('#example tbody tr').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) $(this).removeClass('selected');
    else
    {
        $(this).siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});
   });
</script>


<div id="TableToolsToolbar" class="fg-buttonset ui-helper-clearfix"> </div>
<table><tr><td></td</tr></table>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:100%;" class="display" id="cityworks">
<thead style="background-color:#DC5807; color:White; font-weight:bold;font-size:10pt;">
<tr style="border:solid 1px #000000">
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Requestor</th>
    <th>Site Contact</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Since it's a `GET` request, have you tried typing the url (with appropriate parameters) into the address bar of the browser? This way you could analyze the returned response structure. Sounds like the server is returning the data slightly differently that you're expecting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it.

I had to convert date to string on server side to resolve it.

```
convert(char(10),aa.[requestdate],101) as RequestDate
```

Thanks all for your feedbacks.